# Jquery msg box cant show up jquery

Tags: html, jquery

```js
$('#input1').on('click',function(){
$.msgbox({ 'message':'Msg' });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id = "#input1" type = "text">
```

when clicked input1, I hope jquery msgbox can appear.

Comment: Your input must not has a hastag in the `id` attribute. Further you should tell us which jQuery plugin you are using for this line `$.msgbox({ 'message':'Msg' });` ? It would be even better if you posted a [reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks.UfguFugullu.i think i forget to put in the jquery ui cdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the ID of input you must use `id='input'` then call it with your jquery code.
Example:

```js
$('#input1').on('click',function(){
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
})
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id = "input1" type = "text">

<div id="dialog" title="Hello"></div>
```